# How to create a new user with a set of permissions on AWS RDS mariadb read replica?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have a mariadb AWS RDS. For giving access to my data analytics team, I created a read replica. I can set master password in the AWS RDS console. I did this so that password for main standalone DB is different from read replica password. This is fine.

Now I want to control the read access to certain schemas (databases). I want to create new users and grant specific permissions on specific databases. How do I create a new user on read replica and grant desired permissions.

Comment: You do it on the writer and changes will get propagated to read-replicas.

Comment: Okay. But I could change the master password  for read-replica using aws console. For other users we cannot have different passwords on writer and read-replica. Is that what your are saying?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy. As pointed out by @Marcin.

Create new user on writer instance and grant just the SELECT  permission on desired database. It will propagated to read-replica. And now this new user will see only the permitted database. Even `show databases` will list just the database that we have permitted. Other database names will be hidden from the new user.